# Нажатие на элементы в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

Недавно начал изучать `RecyclerView` и узнал, что для обработки нажатий нужно использовать `setOnClickListener`. В интернете полно информации как реализовать нажатие в адаптере, но все в основном на `Java` и у меня, как у новичка, возникают проблемы с переводом `Java` в `Kotlin`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно обрабатывать нажатия на элементы `RecyclerView` в `Kotlin`. Буду очень признателен, если это будет в виде кода, а не только объяснение словами. Может будут советы, различные фишки в использовании. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В активити/фрагменте создаем адаптер. Первый аргумент - это данные, я для примера передал пустой массив, второй аргумент коллбек в виде лямбды.

```
mAdapter = MyAdapter(ArrayList()) {
            mPresenter.userClicked(it) // тут обрабатываем клик
}
```

Адаптер выглядит так:

```
class MyAdapter(private var items: List<MyObject>,
                      val listener: (MyObject) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindData(items[position])
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindData(mObject: MyObject) {
             itemView.setOnClickListener { listener(gist) }
        }

    }
}
```

Мы передаем в адаптер нашу функцию, которую описываем, когда создаем адаптер.
Подробнее про использование лямбд можно почитать в Kotlin in Action, раздел "Лямбда-выражения"